# Trace the process on how to get to a BOM and its sub BOMs (Bill of Materials)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design

I want to fetch recursive data from a Bill of Material but before that, I need to find the relation between tables. I can’t figure out on how to get to get to a BOM and its sub BOMS (based on tables bellow).

The tables are:

Part: ID (pk), DefaultBOMID (fk from BOM table)

BOM: ID (pk)

BOMITEM: ID(pk), BOMID (fk from BOM table), PARTID (fk from Part table)

I’d appreciate if anyone could trace one example so I can figure out the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first level BOM of a part, it looks like your query would look something like:

```
select BOMITEM.PARTID
from PART.ID
join BOMITEM
on PART.DefaultBomID = BOMITEM.BOM
where Part.ID = 'Part1'
```

Second level would look like:

```
select BOMITEM2.PARTID
from PART.ID
join BOMITEM
on PART.DefaultBomID = BOMITEM.BOM
join PART PART2
on BOMITEM.PARTID = PART2.ID
join BOMITEM BOMITEM2
on PART2.DefaultBomID = BOMITEM2.BOM
where Part.ID = 'Part1'
```

Not sure of the purpose of the BOM table, other than to enforce referential integrity I guess.  Most BOM tables I've seen are just structured with a primary key like (ParentPart, CompoentPart, Route) so it does seem to be an odd structure.